# Stopping media file redirects

Tags: redirect, media, 404-error

We are overriding 404.php to show database generated content like this:

```
/products/x1/
/products/x2/
etc.
```

(if the url is /products/../ the 404 process is converted into a page).

Problem is that we have some media files that have permalink similar to the last part of our database generated content urls.

For example /x1/ which causes /products/x1/ to be redirected to /x1/ instead of showing the database generated content for /products/x1/.

Same thing with a post url like this /x2-specs/. It causes /products/x2/ to be redirected to the post instead of showing the database generated content for /products/x2/.

How do we disable the redirect of all urls that contain /products/?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you looked into and tried so far?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a redirect filter or something than handles the automatic redirections?

Comment: Can you explain how you are "overriding" the 404s?

Comment: If url contains /products/ { drop 404 message and show database generated content instead} else { normal 404 page }

Comment: Is this in a plugin and hooked in somewhere?

Comment: It's in the child theme, overriding the 404.php file of the parent theme.

Comment: That's not overriding them, that's putting content into an error page.

Comment: Ok - but what we need is a way to stop the automatic redirects.

Comment: Are X1, x2 and so on individual products? Could you perhaps flesh your question out with more explicit detail on what you're trying to achieve as I think you need a different approach.

Comment: They are database content, not Woocommerce products or anything related to WP.

Comment: asking about fixing your code without showing it is mostly pointless, even if it is not needed for the question, at its current state it is hard to uderstand what is it that you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

This fixes the problem:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Comment: this will creat duplicate content all over your site

Comment: How come it will create duplicate content?

Comment: hmmm, I probably was somewhat wrong with the exact term, but in the end you have a local problem and your solution is global - disable basic wordpress functionality that ensure that all content have only one url. maybe with other things in place like canonical url this will not hurt SEO but th idea of just globaly disable a core wordpress feature just stinks